# spark write csv file with binary columns

Tags: dataframe, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We have data frame that contains binary columns, when we save the dataframe as csv, the binary column will cause issue for the csv parser.

Is there any way to force spark csv write to write out any binary column in `hex` or `base64` encoded string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check in `df.dtypes` whether type equal `BinaryType` then convert it to [`base64`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#base64) string. In Scala you can write it like this:

```scala
val castedCols = df.dtypes.map { case (c, t) =>
  if (t == "BinaryType") base64(col(c)).as(c) else col(c)
}

val df1 = df.select(castedCols:_*)

df1.write.csv(outputPath)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check the column types, and if the type is binary, you can cast it to a hexadecimal string:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import BinaryType

df_out = df.select([
    F.hex(c.name).alias(c.name)
    if isinstance(c.dataType, BinaryType)
    else F.col(c)
    for c in df.schema
])

df_out.write.csv('output', header=True)
```